# Rename column headers - either after a key database in sas - or after values from first row

Tags: sql, sas

I need to rename the column headers of my variables so they match what I have in  my key list. I attached a picture below to describe what I have and what I need.

[My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2mL1.png)

I don't necesarily need actual code, just an idea of how to make it happen. :)
Thank you so much folks, and so sorry about the changes, I have never posted a question before.

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Please post the text into the question rather than use a picture link. When you post a picture you're expecting people to type our your data and an answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will do that next time. I posted it and initially it was such a mess that I turned it into a picture to keep the formatting. It was ok for visual aid but I will add some code next time to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table like

> **NEW1 NEW2 NEW3**
>   OLDX OLDY OLDZ

And you want to use it to generate rename statement like

```
rename oldx=new1 oldy=new2 oldz=new3 ;
```

Then an easy way to do it is to use PROC TRANSPOSE to convert it into a separate row for each name pair.

```
proc transpose data=have out=names ;
   var _all_;
run;
```

Which will get you a table like

> **_NAME_ COL1**
>   NEW1 OLDX
>   NEW2 OLDY
>   NEW3 OLDZ

Then you can either use PROC SQL to quickly generate a macro variable with the pairs.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select catx('=',col1,_name_) into :rename separated by ' '
  from names;
quit;
data new ;
  set old;
  rename &rename ;
run;
```

If the list of names is too long to put into a single macro variable then just use a data step to generate the rename statement to a text file and use %INCLUDE to run it where you want.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set names end=eof;
  file code ;
  if _n_=1 then put 'rename' ;
  put col1 '=' _name_ ;
  if eof then put ';';
run;
data new ;
  set old;
  %include code ;
run;
```

**EDIT**

You could probably do the last step directly from the data set and skip the proc transpose.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set have ;
  array _X _character_ ;
  file code ;
  put 'rename ' @ ;
  do i=1 to dim(_X);
     oldname = _x(i);
     newname = vname(_x(i));
     put oldname '=' newname @;
  end;
  put / ';' ;
  stop;
run;
```

Comment: I must brush up on my SQL. This is a great solution. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use column aliases to change what's displayed in the results header row.

```
SELECT A AS 'NewA',
       B AS 'OtherB',
       C AS 'diffC'
FROM <<Table>>
```

If you want 'NewA OtherB diffC' as a row in the results, you could do this:

```
SELECT 'NewA' AS 'A',
       'OtherB' AS 'B',
       'diffC' AS 'C'
UNION
SELECT A,
       B,
       C
FROM <<Table>>
```